# AsyncTask cancelling issue

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have a AsyncTask and the doInBackground method is implementing something which takes more time in general. So I am doing two Async Tasks and when the second one starts, I want to stop the first one.

Thus, if I have

```
@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
  books.download(13);
}
```

And the heavy part happens in the download(int) method actually.

Now, when I do cancel(true) on this task, i want the downloading to stop. Thus I want the **books.download(13)** method to get **interrupted**.

Any way to do that?

Comment: I think we need more code. How is books.download implemented? Also, your example does not compile.

Comment: What is your download method doing?

Comment: the books.download(int) is not my method :( that is why I cannot have better control over it. I use it as part of a proprietary library I am using.

Comment: a good post on how to cancel an asynctask http://www.quicktips.in/correct-way-to-cancel-an-asynctask-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

Android does not interrupt your method, you have to do that. cancel(bool) invokes the method onCancelled(bool). If you don't implement this method, nothing happens.

Comment: and does Thread::interrupt() interrupts the thread, as in "kills it" ? Maybe I should go for that...

Comment: Curious, Thread.interrupt() has been deprecated on Oracle Java for years do to it being bad practice (I assume). You probably have to do some try/catch in your thread to handle this, and to clean up nicely. The pretty solution would be to just set a flag which your books.download(int) checks now and again.

Comment: I can't since books.download(int) is not my method, It's from proprietary library I am using.